Rules of conduct in Pridnestrovie
I am traveling in Eastern Europe and want to visit Moldova/Pridnestrovie. Recently I saw news that the name "Transnistria" is banned in this region.
Breakaway Moldovan Region Transnistria Bans Use of Name ‘Transnistria’
Internet surfing also gave information that this term is extremely offensive to locals and can lead to serious conflicts (in particular, I found such information on Facebook and Tripadvisor). However, Wiki states that this is absolutely not an offensive name that should be used by English speakers. I am confused. What is the reason for the ban, why is this name offensive (or not?) and why is the information so contradictory?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
